# Sencha Touch - display a delete icon next to each item in a form?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a FormPanel in Sencha Touch, and I want to add a "delete" icon (or button) to the left of each item in the formpanel's label. I can't seem to find any way to have a form item with "two columns", one for the delete button and one for the Field I'm trying to place the button beside

That is, I have this:

```
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   | Tab 1| Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4 |    |
   |   Label   |   Input               |  
   |   Label   |   Input               |  
   |   Label   |   Input               |  
   |   Label   |   Input               |  
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and I want this:

```
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
       | Tab 1| Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4 |    |
  DEL  |   Label   |   Input               |  
  DEL  |   Label   |   Input               |  
  DEL  |   Label   |   Input               |  
  DEL  |   Label   |   Input               |  
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How can I start to achieve this design? I tried to use Panels as form items, but the buttons stack vertically with the form inputs, instead of horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **hbox** layout ?